# Polymaps - Polygon with label inside from geoJSON

Tags: gis, polygon, geojson, polymaps

I have a map using Polymaps (http://polymaps.org/) and am able to draw polygons based on a geoJSON file. How can I add the name to the polygon.

For example: Here is a bit of my geoJSON

```
"properties": {
    "name": "NH",
```

I want to draw the polygon with the text NH inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current version code, that feature is not implemented on polymaps. You may want to fork polymaps so you can have `<text>` items near each graphic item.